# Аудиопоток по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: html

Мне надо сделать так что-бы по нажатию на `<a>Музыка</a>`
начинал воспроизводится аудиопоток

Знаю что есть `<bgsound>` но он воспроизводит музыку при загрузке страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const audio = document.getElementById("audio");
button.onclick = function() {
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<a id='button'>Музыка</a>

<audio id="audio" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3">
  </audio>
```